# How to build busybox with static binary?

Tags: linux-kernel, compilation, busybox

I'm trying to debug kernel with qemu_8.0.2 + gdb + busybox_1.32.0

But I have a kernel panic when booting:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.
```

So I want to build busybox with  "Build static binary (no shared libs)" option enabled.

But I meet the following error when compiling:

```
  LINK    busybox_unstripped
Your linker does not support --sort-section,alignment
Your linker does not support --sort-common
Static linking against glibc, can't use --gc-sections
Trying libraries: crypt m resolv rt
Failed: -Wl,--start-group  -lcrypt -lm -lresolv -lrt  -Wl,--end-group
Output of:
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wunused -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-value -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-format-security -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wold-style-definition -finline-limit=0 -fno-builtin-strlen -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-guess-branch-probability -funsigned-char -static-libgcc -falign-functions=1 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-labels=1 -falign-loops=1 -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-builtin-printf -Os -static -o busybox_unstripped -Wl,--start-group applets/built-in.o archival/lib.a archival/libarchive/lib.a console-tools/lib.a coreutils/lib.a coreutils/libcoreutils/lib.a debianutils/lib.a klibc-utils/lib.a e2fsprogs/lib.a editors/lib.a findutils/lib.a init/lib.a libbb/lib.a libpwdgrp/lib.a loginutils/lib.a mailutils/lib.a miscutils/lib.a modutils/lib.a networking/lib.a networking/libiproute/lib.a networking/udhcp/lib.a printutils/lib.a procps/lib.a runit/lib.a selinux/lib.a shell/lib.a sysklogd/lib.a util-linux/lib.a util-linux/volume_id/lib.a archival/built-in.o archival/libarchive/built-in.o console-tools/built-in.o coreutils/built-in.o coreutils/libcoreutils/built-in.o debianutils/built-in.o klibc-utils/built-in.o e2fsprogs/built-in.o editors/built-in.o findutils/built-in.o init/built-in.o libbb/built-in.o libpwdgrp/built-in.o loginutils/built-in.o mailutils/built-in.o miscutils/built-in.o modutils/built-in.o networking/built-in.o networking/libiproute/built-in.o networking/udhcp/built-in.o printutils/built-in.o procps/built-in.o runit/built-in.o selinux/built-in.o shell/built-in.o sysklogd/built-in.o util-linux/built-in.o util-linux/volume_id/built-in.o -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--start-group -lcrypt -lm -lresolv -lrt -Wl,--end-group
==========
/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/bin/ld: cannot find -lresolv
/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Note: if build needs additional libraries, put them in CONFIG_EXTRA_LDLIBS.
Example: CONFIG_EXTRA_LDLIBS="pthread dl tirpc audit pam"
make: *** [Makefile:718: busybox_unstripped] Error 1
```

I'm using gcc version 8.5.0 and CentOS 8

I tried yum install libgcrypt, but did not solve the -lcrypt problem.

How could I install these missing libraries?

Comment: Have you tried to have it be built with dynamically linked libraries?